# Is it possible to call npm CLI app's main JS file as if it was ran within a subfolder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, npm, command-line-interface

I have a [small npm CLI library](https://github.com/codsen/chlu-cli) which fixes errors in `changelog.md`'s sitting at the same directory where CLI is called. I'm trying to write at least one unit test for it's CLI part (its API is a separate library and it's well-tested).

It's easy to *trigger* CLI's main JS file using `execa` library, like:

```
execa.sync('./cli.js')
```

but **how do you trigger `cli.js` sitting in a root and meant to be looking for a `./changelog.md` in a root, to execute on a different test file in a subfolder (`/test/changelog.md`)**?

Mind you, there's real `changelog.md` file in the root which has nothing to do with unit test.

(Worst case scenario, we could copy cli.js into `/test/`, call it there via `execa` and delete later, but this looks not DRY solution)

---

My current AVA unit test is below. `seed` is incorrect `changelog.md` file. `intended` is correct `changelog.md` against which we'll compare later. I write `seed` contents into `/test/changelog.md` and want to run a CLI on it. Problem: how do I run `./cli.js` against `/test/package.json`? Mind you, I still want my CLI API to be simple, not accept any arguments with paths (what could be a last resort solution — to accept custom path arguments).

My current test is nearly there, but it runs against root, `./package.json` contents, not `/test/package.json` (which is how API would behave for end-user):

```
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'
import test from 'ava'
import execa from 'execa'

test('01.01 - reads and writes correctly', t => {
  var seed = fs.readFileSync(path.join('test', 'seed.md'), 'utf8')
  var intended = fs.readFileSync(path.join('test', 'intended.md'), 'utf8')
  fs.writeFileSync(path.join('test', 'changelog.md'), seed, 'utf8')

  execa.sync('./cli.js') // <<< PROBLEM, this runs on root, not on ./test/changelog.md!

  t.deepEqual(
    fs.readFileSync(path.join('test', 'changelog.md'), 'utf8'),
    intended,
    '01.01'
  )
})
```

How do you execute an npm CLI package on a different directory when unit testing, if it's meant to be ran on file present at the same level as CLI's JS file?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can just copy the cli.js into your unit test folder as part of the test preparation and run it there. It should work just fine.